# LARAVEL 9 Route [posts.all] not defined error

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9

For some reason Laravel says the route 'posts.all' is not defined. here's my code:

html:

```
<li>
   <a href="{{route('posts.all')}}" class=" waves-effect">
      <i class="ri-calendar-2-line"></i>
         <span>All Posts</span>
   </a>
</li>
```

Laravel Controller group with middleware:

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->name('dashboard')->group(function(){
    Route::controller(\App\Http\Controllers\PostController::class)->group(function(){
        Route::get('/dashboard', 'Dashboard')->name('dashboard');
        Route::get('/posts/all', 'AllPosts')->name('posts.all');
    });
});;
```

however, when i refactor the code to this, it works, but i want to keep in in the PostController

```
Route::get('/posts/all', [\App\Http\Controllers\PostController::class, 'AllPosts'])->name('posts.all');
```

Comment: maybe because you already named it `->name('dashboard')` so it's `dashboardposts.all` and not `posts.all`. in all cases, you can check the names with `php artisan route:list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are grouping everything with the dashboard name.

```
->name('dashboard')->group(function(){});
```

So your route name ends up being `dashboardposts.all`, this can be debugged with `php artisan route:list`.

Assuming you want this structure, i would add a dash between dashboard and posts name, by calling the first name group.

```
->name('dashboard.')
```

Then access it like so.

```
route('dashboard.posts.all')
```